# Reading from messy JSON file and write to excel using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, xls

I am a really beginner in python and I have JSON file with some data that I want to convert to excel.

I have tried using Pandas and convert it but the result was not what I wanted.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_json('test1.json')
print(df)
df.to_excel('test.xls')

Inside my JSON
{
"GraphImages": [
    {
        "__typename": "GraphImage",
        "comments_disabled": false,
        "dimensions": {
            "height": 1350,
            "width": 1080
        },
        "display_url": "https://instagram.fsin1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/26f3c0b4aaac3a511176e6dfe49ecb67/5DED8C15/t51.2885-15/e35/p1080x1080/67240497_370392893870202_8604539984400939460_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fsin1-1.fna.fbcdn.net&ig_cache_key=MjA5NjM3NDQ0NTg2NzI0NzI0Mw%3D%3D.2",
        "edge_media_preview_like": {
            "count": 332
        },
        "edge_media_to_caption": {
            "edges": [
                {
                    "node": {
                        "text": "Midnight’s coat looks absolutely stunning next to our #ALSEDA stool and #LOBBÄK rug. Who else is swooning over the textures and colors in this picture?  : @piquedandpensive\n\n#FurryFriday #MakeHomeCount #IKEASingapore"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "edge_media_to_comment": {
            "count": 1
        },
        "gating_info": null,
        "id": "2096374445867247243",
        "is_video": false,
        "media_preview": "ACEqs5FOCk+31qMOicuQB0Gagm1KOPp83pjp+fSov2NLdy20TfX6VSn+7UMergn5lwPY5/wq3PiePzEOcc8dx3z7ij1F6GVRSZoqhGhcDzYMDknn8qwDlsKBkjtW/btu/dnqv6j/AD/SriRohJAAJ6nFRexVrnJ7SDg8VraUGLMf4cYI9Sen5DNT3On+a+5WCr6Y/OpdotIdq9ex9Se/+e2Kd7iSszMwtFMxRVEmg6HO5eCKkW5YfeGfpTSaM0rXHexN9pz0X86qTsWGTTyagl6UWC9ytmim0UxH/9k=",
        "owner": {
            "id": "404656175"
        },
        "shortcode": "B0X0XOSH6aL",
        "tags": [
            "FurryFriday",
            "IKEASingapore",
            "ALSEDA",
            "MakeHomeCount",
            "LOBBÄK"
        ],
        "taken_at_timestamp": 1564127330,
        "thumbnail_resources": [
            {
                "config_height": 150,
                "config_width": 150,
                "src": "https://instagram.fsin1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/28e7bedc1e40061e40cd0d99ee7a7c77/5DD5FC57/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.180.1440.1440/s150x150/67240497_370392893870202_8604539984400939460_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fsin1-1.fna.fbcdn.net&ig_cache_key=MjA5NjM3NDQ0NTg2NzI0NzI0Mw%3D%3D.2.c"
            },
            {
                "config_height": 240,
                "config_width": 240,
                "src": "https://instagram.fsin1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/f381e45a105830efd388936dc70c2070/5DCC4A1D/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.180.1440.1440/s240x240/67240497_370392893870202_8604539984400939460_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fsin1-1.fna.fbcdn.net&ig_cache_key=MjA5NjM3NDQ0NTg2NzI0NzI0Mw%3D%3D.2.c"
            },
            {
                "config_height": 320,
                "config_width": 320,
                "src": "https://instagram.fsin1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/d04db5627593495196c016b2d80e92a8/5DCCEDA7/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.180.1440.1440/s320x320/67240497_370392893870202_8604539984400939460_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fsin1-1.fna.fbcdn.net&ig_cache_key=MjA5NjM3NDQ0NTg2NzI0NzI0Mw%3D%3D.2.c"
            },
            {
                "config_height": 480,
                "config_width": 480,
                "src": "https://instagram.fsin1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/e222b4716f8a7e426ebb688f8bec4aa3/5DCC56FD/t51.2885-15/e35/c0.180.1440.1440/s480x480/67240497_370392893870202_8604539984400939460_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fsin1-1.fna.fbcdn.net&ig_cache_key=MjA5NjM3NDQ0NTg2NzI0NzI0Mw%3D%3D.2.c"
            },
            {
                "config_height": 640,
                "config_width": 640,
                "src": "https://instagram.fsin1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/5ae19eafeb84cedc67324ab46f2cc407/5DDC104C/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.180.1440.1440/s640x640/67240497_370392893870202_8604539984400939460_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fsin1-1.fna.fbcdn.net&ig_cache_key=MjA5NjM3NDQ0NTg2NzI0NzI0Mw%3D%3D.2.c"
            }
        ],
        "thumbnail_src": "https://instagram.fsin1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/5ae19eafeb84cedc67324ab46f2cc407/5DDC104C/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c0.180.1440.1440/s640x640/67240497_370392893870202_8604539984400939460_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fsin1-1.fna.fbcdn.net&ig_cache_key=MjA5NjM3NDQ0NTg2NzI0NzI0Mw%3D%3D.2.c",
        "urls": [
            "https://instagram.fsin1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/26f3c0b4aaac3a511176e6dfe49ecb67/5DED8C15/t51.2885-15/e35/p1080x1080/67240497_370392893870202_8604539984400939460_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fsin1-1.fna.fbcdn.net&ig_cache_key=MjA5NjM3NDQ0NTg2NzI0NzI0Mw%3D%3D.2"
        ],
        "username": "ikeasingapore"
    }
]
```

}

I expected the result for each value in new column, however, they all stacked up in 1 column.
This is the result of my current code

[image: what I got]
[What I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThHy3.png)

[image]

Comment: Please add the content of your JSON file as well as what you'd expect the Excel file to look like.

Comment: @AKX Yeap I did it

Answer (score -1):

Use a for loop to iterate through the file, the thing you are doing currently is reading the whole file at one time and writing it into excel.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_json('test1.json')
fm=open('./file.xlsx')
for i in  range(len(df)):
    line=df.iloc[i]
    print(line)
    l1=str(line)
    fm.write(l1)
fm.close
```

This will write all the different lines in different rows in the excel sheet and save the sheet in the folder where the script is saved.

Comment: Tried it, it gave me "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Series"

Comment: Try it once again with the applied changes it should work.

Comment: It says not writeable, hmmm.

Comment: You can't write a valid XLSX file with just `open` anyway.